# How to supply password in crontab

Tags: linux, cron, mount

I am writing the command in crontab and its output is first asking the password.

Is there any way to supply the password with command like

```
mount -a < password
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:  with Expect http://wiki.tcl.tk/201 > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect >.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Seems like you must be mounting some type of remote filesystem.  Those usually have special options that allow you to supply the password if you don't want to muck around with 'expect'.  For samba, you can do this:

`mount -t smbfs -o username=thisguy,password=abc123 //winserver/stuff /mnt/stuff`

The username and password options can also be placed in your `/etc/fstab` file in the column with the options like ro,rw,noauto, etc.

Comment: Actually i am using the crontab as root but still it is asking for password